# How can I load a page in specific frame?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am having 3 frames in one page. Frame 1 contains the heading, Frame 2 contains menus and frame 3 contains the pages. When I click the link in frame 2 the page is loading in frame 3. But when I right click and open with new tab if I give only that page is loading in new tab. I want to load that page with 3 frames only and the page should be loaded in third frame only.

This means that if I in any way open that url, it has to load the page which contains 3 frames and the specified page should load in frame 3 only. Can anyone tell me how can I do this?.

My frame markup is as follows

```
 <frameset  framespacing="0" rows="140,*">
 <frame id="head" frameborder="0" src="http://localhost:1359/WebSite1/Head.aspx"      name="frame_a" scrolling="no" noresize="noresize"  border="0" onload="framespacing='0'">
 <frameset  framespacing="0" cols="15%,80%">
 <frame id="Menu" frameborder="0" src="http://localhost:1359/WebSite1/Menus.aspx" name="frame_b" >
 <frame id="Page"frameborder="0" src="http://localhost:1359/WebSite1/HomePage.aspx" name="frame_c" style="background-color:White" >
 </frameset>
 </frameset>
```

Comment: Post your frameset markup.

Comment: If you can, ditch the frames and use something else. Perhaps a master page?

Answer (score 1):

You open a link in a specific frame by using the target attribute of the anchor element.

```
<a href="page.html" target="frameid">Link</a>
```

Comment: ya this is i have given it works properly when you click on the link.But on the same link if i right click and open with newtab if i do the single target page is loading without the frame page.that should not be in my case. i want to load 3 frames and in the third frame page.html or page1.html etc has to load if you right click and open with new tab given also.

Answer (score 1):

`target=""` attribute of your `<a>` (anchor) is designed to do this.

Specify the ID of the frame, or use one of the "special" targets:

- `_blank` (new page)
- `_top`
- `_parent`
- `_self`

More info can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

Comment: yes in the same way i am loading by click... but what to do for right click and open with new tab?

Comment: @Raghuveera: that's a client's decision to open a new tab, and therefore you have no control over how it's handled. If I, as the user, want the link in a new tab who are you (as the webmaster) to stop me? At best you can check `window.top` and reload the frameset if the page is loaded outside of a frame.

Comment: Ya you are right. But you if you open mysql in web browser that also contains 2 or 3 frames. if you right click and open,the opened page will open with all the frames in new tab.how it is possible?

Comment: They're [forcing frames](http://javascript.about.com/library/blfrm3.htm) most likely (where they check if `top.location == self.location` on page load and (if not) redirects them to the master page).

Answer (score 0):

Please use On a button click event (or some other event):

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('PageName.aspx','FrameName');</script>")
```